# Gauss' Lemma application

Tags: number-theory

```
Using Gauss’ Lemma, is x^2 ≡ −3 mod 13 solvable?
```

I know that the Lemma is (a/p)=(-1)^n but I don't get how to apply it when a is negative.

```
 - a*2=-6
 - a*3=-9
 - a*4=-12
```

How do I know when to stop to be able to determine the Legendre symbol?

New to number theory would appreciate any feedback. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Look at the first example on its [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(number_theory)) to see how to apply it and come back then.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I've read the wiki page as well as others. I am not looking for anyone to solve it for me. I just want to understand it.

Comment: So what don't you understand ? Put it in the question...Is it the proof you don't get? The question you asked is answered easily.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma it is the same method even if a is negative? or do i have to transform it before hand?

Comment: No that’s not needed. Positive and negative have no real meaning modulo $13$. $-3\equiv 10$ anyway.

Comment: Yes. Just consider the first 6 multiples.

Comment: so considering the first 6 multiples, we have -6,-9,-12,-15,-18,-21. Usually we would reduce by the modulo if possible, determine how many integers are greater than p/2 and we are done. Here i can just say that it is not solvable since a is negative? @HennoBrandsma

Comment: $-6$ is just $7$ etc. Reduce to its standard form in $\{0,1,\ldots,12\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$-3 \equiv 10$ so we consider the first $6$ multiples (because $6=\frac{13-1}{2}$):

$$10,20,30,40,50,60 \equiv 10, 7, 4, 1, 11, 8$$

and how many are $> 6$?

Comment: 4 of them are greater meaning n=4

Comment: @angryhorse  So the symbol has value $+1 = (-1)^4$ and so $x^2= -3$ is solvable.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Much appreciated.

Comment: @angryhorse You can always turn negative numbers into positive ones by adding $13$(repeatedly if needed); it's all the same class of integers.

Comment: yeah that's the part that I did not get at the beginning. Now that i know that it felt like a stupid question to ask hahahah. Thank you!

Comment: @angryhorse there are no stupid questions, just badly explained ones. After the edits and comments it became clear what your actual issue was... Hope you can make new steps now. All this modulo stuff takes some getting used to. But it's useful stuff, really.

Comment: Thank you so much I really do appreciate it.